# Pydantic: env_nested_delimiter for a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

Pydantic introduced in version `1.9`*-ish* [`env_nested_delimiter`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/settings/#parsing-environment-variable-values), a mechanism for parsing env vars in a convenient way.

I have this module in settings:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, BaseSettings


class SubModel(BaseModel):
    v1: str
    v2: bytes
    v3: int


class Settings(BaseSettings):
    v0: str
    sub_models: [SubModel]

    class Config:
        env_nested_delimiter = '__'


print(Settings().dict())
```

Is there a way to define elements of my `sub_models` (a `list` of `SubModel` instances) in the .env file with delimiters? I've already tried:

```
SUB_MODELS__0__SUB_MODEL__V2=00
SUB_MODELS__0__SUB_MODEL__V3=01
SUB_MODELS__0__SUB_MODEL__DEEP__V4=01

SUB_MODELS__1__SUB_MODEL__V2=nested-10
SUB_MODELS__1__SUB_MODEL__V3=11
SUB_MODELS__1__SUB_MODEL__DEEP__V4=12
```

but it did not work. I'm not sure if it's possibile with the current version of pydantic. Maybe delimiters are just restricted to dict-*like* data structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking into the [source code](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/blob/be246701c504824f4bfc291209ac057ff7df0bc2/pydantic/env_settings.py#L220-L237), it seems not possibile. At least in version *1.9.0*.